# Quantum circuit calculating sum of two quantum states $|a\rangle + |b\rangle$

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer, superposition, quantum-states

What is the simplest quantum circuit which takes states $|a\rangle$ and $|\rangle$ as its input, and outputs their (normalized) sum $c (|\rangle+|\rangle$)? Here $c$ is a normalization constant to make the output a valid quantum state. The use of Ancilla qubits is allowed. It might also be necessary to use some kind of "encoding" for states $|a\rangle$ and $|\rangle$.

---

***[Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11554/55)***

Comment: What does "encoding" mean?  And can |a> and |b> be arbitrary states, or orthogonal basis states?  In either case, what would a valid "encoding" be?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an exact [cross-post of a question on QuantumComputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11554/simple-quantum-circuit-to-calculate-sum-of-input-states-a-rangle-b-rangle). If you do not get an acceptable answer on QC.SE after a reasonable amount of time (>= 1 week), feel free to ping one of the mods and we can consider re-opening it here.

Comment: did you have a look at [Oszmaniec et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04955)?

Comment: @glS Nice catch!  Theorem 1!  (Also, *that's* how one states the question precisely!)

Comment: @tpg2114 This cross-posting between pse and qc.se has become kind of a habit.  Do we have a general policy on that?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The general policy is [as it always was](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-that-you-previously-asked-in-other-se-site) and it is strongly discouraged. It can be acceptable, however, [if it is tailored to each specific site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/174806). In other words, how a physicist might answer something about QC could be different than how an engineer/computer scientist might answer it over on QC.SE, and a question should be tailored for those audiences.

Comment: And I guess if it's targeting physicists on both sites such that it's identical and the target audience is the same, then it really just shouldn't be cross-posted unless/until it has been on one for awhile and not gotten any traction.

Comment: @tpg2114 Indeed, historically I had such a policy in mind (the linked meta post precedes qc.se).  I just observed that this has happened rather frequently recently (usually glS or someone else would mark those questions).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch As always, feel free to flag things you want us to look at (which I know you know -- thank you for doing it!). Our site has considerable overlap with math, chemistry, astronomy (in that case, exact overlap), and sometimes engineering -- among others, which now includes QC. Which is all great and most of the time, questions can be tailored for the specific audience to get new insights that would make cross-posting okay.

Comment: @tpg2114 For a second, I thought you meant to say QC is part of engineering :-o

Comment: @NorbertSchuch btw, in case you were not aware, we do have a "policy" on cross-posting (or at least some discussion about it) on QC. See [this thread](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/404/55).

Comment: @glS Yes, I had a vague memory that this was discussed on qc.se.

Answer (score 4):

Such a circuit cannot exist. To see why, assume $|b\rangle = e^{i\phi}|a\rangle$. Then, the input $|a\rangle|b\rangle$ is mapped to $|a\rangle + e^{i\phi}|b\rangle=(1+e^{i\phi})|a\rangle$, which (i) is not normalizable independent of $\phi$, (ii) is identically zero for $\phi=\pi$, and (iii) whose output *normalization*, and whose *output state modulo a phase* depends on the *unphysical* state of the input.

In brief, it is incompatible with linearity.

After all, if the map - let's call it $U$ - were linear, on input $|v\rangle$, it should produce the output $U|v\rangle$, and therefore due to linearity, on input $e^{i\phi}|v\rangle$ the output $e^{i\phi}U|v\rangle$.  (As you can see: You don't even need linearity in this step, you just need homogeneity over the complex numbers!)  Clearly, the argument above shows that for the map you quote, this is not the case.

Comment: Hi Norbert, thanks for attempting to answer, but obviously we assume that the state is normalized, so your counterexample isn't valid. Nevertheless, a *different* linearity argument is likely the explanation why the problem cannot be solved :)

Comment: I added a normalization constant c to the output, which is what I initially meant with "normalized"

Comment: @SamuelBosch My counterexample ***implies*** that linearity is violated: If the map would be linear, applying it to $|v\rangle$ and $e^{i\phi}|v\rangle$ would give the same output ***up to a global phase***.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean with this argument. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Dear @SamuelBosch, how about this: *You* write down *clearly* what you mean. And by "clearly" I mean formulas, not just words. Make dependencies clear, i.e. if $c$ depends on $a$ and $b$, write $c(a,b)$. Make clear what $|a\rangle$ is, i.e.: $|a\rangle\in\mathrm{set}$.  *Then* I will be happy to explain why such a map cannot exist.  Now you want me to state assumptions and conclusions, just to risk that you later complain that those weren't your assumptions.

Comment: Dear Norbert, see the answer I provided below for more details :)

Comment: also, $c$ is just a normalization. So when the state is $c|\psi\rangle$, then clearly $c$ must be $c=1/\sqrt{\langle \psi | \psi \rangle}$, to make sure it is a valid quantum state

Comment: @SamuelBosch As said below: If c normalizes it: Just say what c is.  You might have had in mind some probabilistic protocol.